# Making Ajax call to another domain from a react app rendered using lightning:container

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-container

I am making a custom lightning component in which i am rendering a React app using `lightning:container`.
In that react app i have to make ajax calls to another domain `api.xyz.com` to fetch and update the data.

Are these cross domain api calls possible somehow? Because the iframe in which  `lightning:container` renders the react app has its src set to something else.
I have looked over forums and documentation but unable to come to a conclusion. Please help. Any example will help.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `api.xyz.com` domain as a [CSP Trusted Site](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=0)? Are you getting any particular errors in the browser's dev console? I'm also assuming that your react app is stored as a static resource on Salesforce and rendered from there.

Comment: yes did that only once i found out about CSP trusted sites on salesforce.
worked after that. please add this as an answer. will accept and close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are making an API call to the external domain `api.xyz.com` you need to add it as a [CSP Trusted Site](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=0) or Salesforce will block it. That will tell Salesforce to add the appropriate directives to the page's CSP headers, thereby allowing you to make cross-domain requests. You'd also need to do this if you were trying to load images, fonts, or styles (but NOT javascript, which needs to be in a static resource) from an external site.